# Microseurrises: Two instances with Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, microservices, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a method in my application that is executed every 5 ms (using the `@Scheduled (fixedDelay = 5)`). It gets from the DB entity and changes its status depending on the business logic. Suppose I have 2 instances of my app.
How can I do that different instances don't get the same messages from DB and don't process the same messages?
I mean **instance A** get message with `id=1` and **instance B** get message with `id=2`, not with `id=1`

Comment: Do the two instances live in the same JVM?  Do they communicate with each other through any mechanisms?  Do you have control over the db?

Comment: @BeUndead  in different JVMs. No, don't communicate (how could communication help?). App just connect to DB.

Comment: But if I say 'add a column to the DB to track processed/processing messages', is that a possibility, or does someone else specify the db schema?

Comment: And communication could help if they connected over HTTP or similar to coordinate who was going to do what.  One sends a message to the other saying 'I'm going to pick up task A', and then the other knows not to do that one when it comes to look at available tasks to start.

Comment: @BeUndead I can add a flag to an entity, but where is the guarantee that 2 instances will not simultaneously take the same entity and will not change this flag for it?

Comment: If it's in the database, then you do versioned updates (with a version field as well as the flag, the version field increments everytime that entity is committed).  You then make it so that a commit will fail if the version field doesn't match what you _thought_ it was when you started.  One transaction will succeed and update the flag to 'processing'.  The other one will get an `Exception` and from that it can infer 'someone else must have picked this up'.

Comment: You can do something similar with an `AtomicBoolean` using the `compareAndSet` method.  If you do `if (compareAndSet(false, true)) { /* Do task */ }` then only one of them will succeed.  The other one would fail the comparison check and get `false` (so not enter the `if` block).  But that was if they were in the same JVM.#

Comment: @BeUndead it turns out that versioning is configured in the database, right? Those. Instances A and B  get an entity with id = 1 version = 1, instance A updated the entity, it became id = 1 version = 2, instance B tries to update and gets an error from the database, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :).  If you're using hibernate, then there's an `@Version` annotation you can put on some `Long` field.  But I don't know what libraries/APIs you're using.

Comment: @BeUndead spring jpa(hibirnate)

Comment: @BeUndead and if I don't want to store so much information (with versioning at least 2 records are stored)?

Comment: Define 'record'.  There's two additional columns (one could be a boolean, and one a bigint or similar).  And if you're not ok with adding two tiny extra points of data to the database, you won't like any of my other suggestions.